# KingswaySoft: Nav source component filter InvoiceLines

Tags: nav, kingswaysoft

I need to filter the Invoice Lines so that it only reads the lines where the Invoice Header exists.
For instance:

where InvoiceId in (Select InvoiceId from PostedSalesInvoices)

Is it possible to encode it with XML?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. For this requirement, we encourage you to reach out to us with more details through our support channel so that we can have a close look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.